# Using wormholes to redirect projectiles

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, physics, science-fiction, wormholes

A civilization has developed wormhole generators for transportation between solar systems. Some smart fellow thought it would be a good idea to try and create wormholes in such a way so anything fired at a fleet would go through the wormhole, and appear *behind* the hostile fleet, which may land a couple lucky hits.

I was wondering wether you could predict how a projectile could enter and leave a wormhole.

---

**Visuals** (not to scale)

(O - wormhole entrance/exit) (! - hostile fleet) (= - friendly fleet)

The projectile is fired at hostile fleet

! -----> =

The friendly fleet creates the wormholes

O ! -----> O =

The projectile enters the wormhole, and one could predict which direction it came out, so you could hit the hostile fleet with their own weapons.

O---> ! ------O =

Would something like this be possible?

Comment: I was under the impression that these sorts of shenanigans were routine in that Portal video game.

Comment: @Will Aye, but a game does not always contain sound science.

Comment: I am pretty sure sound science will not survive the wormholes you describe.  Or maybe vice versa.

Comment: your wormhole whether it is or asymmetric(2 throats) or time-dependent(self-explanatory I hope) requires you to gather lots of exotic matter at one place, at one time and that's the biggest challenge! solve that and the universe is your playground ;D

Comment: This is an exciting question, but without knowing how your wormhole generator work, a "yes" answer will be as right as "no" answer. I'd be tempted to answer "Sure! Why not?". Please provide why you think it is not possible (for example, the generator is not very accurate in creating the output wormhole)

Comment: @Vylix Mostly along the lines of whether projectiles would keep their speed and direction going through a wormhole. If they were affected in a way which was not terribly predictable, i.e. if it came in at 90 degrees, but then came out at 15 degrees due to a random factor, then this theory may not work. I was planning for the output wormhole to be extremely inaccurate as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wormholes are *not* in the realm of science, even though science doesn't forbid them.

Is it thus impossible to say what would really happen if and when such a technology would become available.

One safe bet, however, would be Newton still holds true: this means the projectile would emerge with the same speed vector. Positioning accurately the wormholes endpoints it would thus be possible to "aim" incoming projectiles with correspondingly high accuracy.

Comment: In this case, would it be best for me to remove the science-based tag?

Comment: Science does forbid wormholes.

Comment: As ZioByte mentioned, wormholes are not yet certain things.

In Bose's paper, where he introduced the concept with Einstein, it was just curved space linking two points. The orientation of that linkage has been proposed (not by Bose, but can't recall who) to be steerable. So, yes. You might be able to do that.

Comment: @A.C.A.C.Total nonsense! Wormholes arise out of various solutions of general relativity. While their existence hasn't been empirically proven or disproven, to say science forbids them is untenable. They are theoretically possible, their actual reality remains uncertain. Something different from forbidding their existence.

Comment: Wormholes are an abstract mathematical concept in physics at present.  They're not considered traversable and have no relationship at all with the sci-fi conceptions of them.  [Here a previous answer of mine on this subject](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/81796/32391).

Comment: @ZioByte It is Newton's laws that makes instantaneous movement from one place to another impossible as well. So essentially you are saying "With wormholes we can break Newton's laws, but Newton's laws still hold true". That is a contradiction. Either you can break Newton's laws or you cannot. If you can break Newton's laws you can just redirect the momentum vector.

Comment: @MichaelK: Newton's laws hold in a flat space. They already need rework in our Einsteinian space (geodetic for "straight" line) and wormholes introduce discontinuity. JamesMcLellan: I was unaware of steerability, thanks for pointing it out.